# Kotlin - Dynamically instantiate all inner classes

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Here is the situation I am looking to solve - A service is consuming JSON and doing some processing. Based on a string value in one of the JSON fields I want to instantiate one of a number of classes implementing an interface.

In essence I am trying to give the JSON input the ability to control which functionality to use.

A simplified version of my current solution is as follows

```
interface A{
    val name: String
    fun doSomething()
}

class choseImplementation(val jsonChoice: String){
    inner class B: A{
        override val name = "B"
        override fun doSomething(){// Do B things}
    }

    inner class C: A{
        override val name = "C"
        override fun doSomething(){// Do C things}
    }

    init {
        // Instantiate B and C
        // Compare B.name and C.name with jsonChoice
        // Choose the name that matches jsonChoice and expose the instantiated class
        // The exposed class will be used in downstream processing
    }
}
```

choseImplementation is given a string and exposes the proper implementation to be used by the system.

Right now I am manually instantiating each class within the init function and then comparing, which means I have to change the code in two places, add the D class then incorporate it in the init function

I want to be able to add a new inner class (D implements A) and have it automatically added to the process of being instantiated and selected.

Solutions outside this template are welcome

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`nestedClasses` property of `KClass<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html) to get all of the classes that are nested in a particular class. Then you will need to filter the result to get only the `inner` classes using the [`isInner` property](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/is-inner.html).

Then instantiate the classes normally using either the [`primaryConstructor`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/primary-constructor.html) or finding a constructor the desired signature, but, since that would be an `inner` class, note that all of its constructors have an additional first (and potentially the single) parameter to which you need to pass the instance of the outer class.

Together, it would look like:

```
class ChooseImplementation(val jsonChoice: String) {
    /* Inner classes omitted... */ 

    init {
        val innerClass = this::class.nestedClasses
            .filter { it.isInner }
            .find { it.simpleName == jsonChoice }
            ?: error("Could not find inner class $jsonChoice")

        val instance = innerClass.primaryConstructor!!.call(this)

        /* Use the instance... */
    }
}
```

Note that to use the Kotlin reflection API, you need to have a dependency on `kotlin-reflect`.